# Checking if two pointers are on the same page

Tags: c, pointers

I saw this interview question and wanted to know if my function is doing what it's supposed to or if there's a better way to do this.

Here's the exact quote of the question:

> The operating system typically allocates memory in pages such that the base address of the page are 0, 4K, 8K etc. Given two addresses (pointers), write a function to find if two pointers are on the same page. Here's the function prototype: int AreOnSamePage (void * a, void * b);

Here's my implementation. I made it return 4 if it's between 4k and 8k. It returns 1 if it's between 0 and 4k and it returns -1 if it's over 8k away. Am I getting the right addresses? The interview question is worded vaguely. Is it correct to use long's since the addresses could be pretty big?

```
    int AreOnSamePage(void* a, void* b){
       long difference = abs(&a - &b);
       printf("%ld %ld\n",(long)&a,(long)&b);
       if(difference > 8000)
          return -1;
       if(difference >= 4000)
          return 4;
       return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you taking addresses of `a` and `b`?

Comment: I took the addresses because the question stated the addresses. I'm a noob when it comes to pointers.

Comment: @Aidenator *Given two addresses (pointers)* The question makes it very clear that *address* and *pointer* are synonyms.

Comment: But the addresses of the objects `a` and `b` **point to**. Which would be the **values** of the pointers. You take the addresses of the pointers themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are pointers, so the distance between them is:

`ptrdiff_t difference = (ptrdiff_t) abs((char *)a - (char *) b)`

But you don't need it.
Two pointers are on the same page, if

`(uintptr_t)a / 4096 == ( uintptr_t ) b / 4096`

Else they are on different pages.
So:

```
    int AreOnSamePage(void* a, void* b) {
       const size_t page_size = 4096;
       if ( (uintptr_t) a / page_size == (uintptr_t) b / page_size)
            return 1;
       else 
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try this on a 64 bit machine with 32 bit `int`. Hint: C99 intruduced 2 types for such.

Comment: The correct type for the distance between pointers is `ptrdiff_t`. You also shouldn't cast the pointers to `int`, as it's not guaranteed that `int` is wide enough to hold memory addresses (see Olaf's comment). You should use `uintptr_t` instead. Last but not least, page sizes are powers of 2; 4 KB is 4096, not 4000,

Comment: Wow, I did not realize it would be easy as dividing by the page size. Thanks @Randl. I like this way better than the bitmask methods other people are using although both do make sense.

Comment: @Aidenator: It depends on the architecture which version is the better one. But you should not use a variable for the page_size, but a global constant, best from a system header, if available or inquired by a system-API. The division by a variable cannot be optimized that easy. Note that C ins not C++, thus `const` has a different meaning.

Comment: There are still `int`s left.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code.

1. You are comparing addresses of function parameters (they are side by side, on stack), not pointers
2. You for no reason compare the `difference` with 8000
3. 4K != 4000
4. Imagine one address is 3K, other is 5K, according to your code, they are on the same page.
5. Bad choice of return values

Comment: `long` is ok for this?

Comment: @Olaf What do you mean?

Comment: OP uses `long` for his calculations.

Comment: `intptr_t` would be a better choice

Comment: `uintptr_t` even better.

Answer (score 0):

The name `AreOnSamePage()` implies that the function returns either `0` or `1`; I'd find it odd to have it return `-1`, `4` or other values.

If a page is 4KB, then it means you need 12 bits to index each byte inside a page (because 2^12 = 4096), so as long as the `N-12` most significant bits of both pointer values compare equal, then you know they are on the same page (where `N` is the size of a pointer).

So you can do this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

static const uintptr_t PAGE_SIZE = 4096;
static const uintptr_t PAGE_MASK = ~(PAGE_SIZE-1);

int AreOnSamePage(void *a, void *b) {
    return (((uintptr_t) a) & PAGE_MASK) == (((uintptr_t) b) & PAGE_MASK);
}
```

`PAGE_MASK` is a bit mask that has all `N-12` most significant bits set to 1 and the 12 least significant bits set to 0. By doing the bitwise `AND` with an address, we effectively clear the least significant 12 bits (the offset into the page), so we can compare only the other bits that matter.

Note that `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be wide enough to store pointer values, unlike `long`.

Comment: This is C, not C++, so better use `#define`s instead of variables.

Comment: @Olaf I don't see how that is in any way "better". If anything, I actually prefer variables over `#define`s.

Comment: The compiler can optimize constants much better for most CPUs. Let alone that such values should normally be defined in a system header (library for variables).

Comment: @Olaf Then you might as well use an `enum`. Macros are a dangerous way to program because they change the lexical structure of the program (aside from the fact that I find it very hard to believe that you would even see a difference in performance), so it's generally good advice to avoid it altogether. Don't take my word for it: have a look at the first chapter of *The Practice of Programming*.

Comment: "Then you might as well use an enum" [**No**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.3p2). Don't tell me. Macros are the C way to defined symbolic names for constants. If you want another type than `int` you can't do otherwise. As I said, C is not C++. And yes, there can be great differences. Possibly not that much, if you are only used to work on the lager irons like PC and do not need to squeeze every MIPS out of your code. I'm pretty confident I know what I do for a very long time. Theory vs. Practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your aptempt to solve the interview's question is wrong.

You should be comparing `a` and `b`. Not `&a` and `&b`.

But even then it would still be wrong.
Consider pointer `a` points to last position of page 0 and pointer `b` points to first position of page 1. And page 1 is the one after page 0.
Their difference is 1. But they are in different pages.

In order to correctly implement it you should consider that a page is 4Kib long. 4Kib = 2^12 = 4096. So all the bits of a pair of pointers save for the last 12 will be equal if they are in the same page.

```
#include<stdint.h>
int AreOnSamePage(void* a, void* b){
  return ((intptr_t)a & ~(intptr_t)0xFFF) == 
         ((intptr_t)b & ~(intptr_t)0xFFF);
}
```

A more concise but equivalent implementation :

```
int AreOnSamePage(void* a, void* b){
  return ((intptr_t)a)>>12 == ((intptr_t)b)>>12;
}
```

Comment: Which answer are you refering to? Do not answer an answer. Also using signed types here is not recommended. And a page size can be different. Do not use magic values in your code!

Comment: @Olaf I believe by answer he means the OP's attempt at solving the question.

Comment: Yes, I mean that, I've ammended my answer to better reflect it.

Comment: @Olaf. Why are signed types not recommended? Can you provide an example in which that code will work incorrectly?

Comment: Because of sign-manipulation issues. You cannot assume to have 2s or 1s complement. And C actually does **not** make any assertions if you manipulate the value of an integer containing a "pointer value". So this is basically not covered by the standard. Either way, I only know one platform which uses signed addresses and that is certainly not used here (Transputer - just "wikipedia" it), all others use unsigned pointers anyway. (to make it clear: I did not say this wil not work, just it is not recommended). After all, the (somewhat) related type `size_t` is also unsigned.

Comment: The problem is not going to have a solution if the value of an integer containing a "pointer value" can't be manipulated; so the accepted answer is wrong. But it does have a solution. Because the problem states that we deal with addresses(pointers). The answer may be wrong with compilers and architectures where we can't assume a pointer is a memory address. But here we can, read the question carefully. Also, my answer is independient of 2s or 1s complement, works in both cases. The only real mistake I had was operator precedence; & has higher precedence than == and that made my code fail.

Comment: I did not state it **cannot** be manipuated (heck, I have to in my own OS code, of course). I just state it is not covered by the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.4), which does not make any assumptions on manipulating the transfered value. In fact, the standard does not even allow to compare the pointers as such, as they do not necessarily point into the same array or to the same object. Still one has to rely on this working in some kinds of code. Please point me at where I stated any of the answers using `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` would be wrong and I'll revisite.

Comment: I actually wanted to add a well meant hint, not start a discussion and the least I wanted is to offend you. If you are just defending your answer: no need; I did not downvote and it is acceptable for me as-is. If you are really interested, feel free to read the standard and think about the arguments I brought up vs. the pros of using a signed integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88281/discussion-between-jose-antonio-dura-olmos-and-olaf).

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you should use `uintptr_t` to proces the pointers. Your code is, however, wrong, as you test the distance, not the page. Also, you foget that computers use powers of two. `8000` is none; that would be `8192`. similar for `4000`.

The fastest approach for the test would be:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// this should better be found in a system header:
#define PAGESIZE 4096U

bool samePage(void *a, void *b)
{
    return ((uintptr_t)a ^ (uintptr_t)b) < PAGESIZE;
}
```

or:

```
    return !(((uintptr_t)a ^ (uintptr_t)b) / PAGESIZE);
```

Note the result of the division will be converted to `bool`. If this is used as an inline, it will just tested for zero/not zero.

The XOR will zero all bits which are equal. So if any higher order bits differ, they will be set after XOR, and make the result >= PAGESIZE. This saves you one division or masking.

This requires PAGESIZE to be a power of two, of course.

Comment: The XOR is confusing me. Could you explain that a little more? It will make all the bits that differ from each other 1.

Comment: @Aidenator: Right. So, if any bits higher or same as the single bit in `PAGESIZE` are set after the XOR, the comparison will fail, returning `false`. If both pointers are in the same page, the upper bits will be equal, thus XOR clears them all, the rest is `< PAGESIZE`.

Comment: I just played around with a few numbers and see what it's doing now. Very clever.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, XOR has some interesting use-cases.

Comment: @Olaf. You are manipulating the value of an integer containing a "pointer value". So you are providing an answer which you yourself consider to be wrong.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: Where did I state this? There is no ther solution for this problem and I did not claim yours is wrong. I just stated that it "is not covered by the standard".